# Exclude library directory from being search for by CMake

Tags: cmake

I have two different locations for the same library .so file and need to prevent CMake from searching for both locations. How can I do something like this with something similar to but opposite in effect of the 
include_directories macro in my CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3afind_library) lists directories order, in which CMake performs search. As you can see, CMake would always pick up library from `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib` unless you set `NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH`.

You can play with `HINTS` until you get desired effect, but it'd better if you explain why you need such thing in the first place.